# Does the existence of a nondegenerate paring of finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ imply that $V \simeq W^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Bott & Tu, *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*, at the beginning of the discussion of Poincaré duality (page 44 in my edition), I find the following definition and claim:

> A pairing between two finite-dimensional vector spaces $\langle\ ,\ \rangle \colon V \otimes W \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *nondegenerate* if $\langle v, w \rangle = 0$ for all $w$ implies $v = 0$; equivalently, the map $v \mapsto \langle v,\ \rangle$ should define an isomorphism $V \xrightarrow{\sim} W^*$.

I can see immediately how a pairing implies a map $V \to W^*$, and it's obvious that if $V$ is nondegenerate such a map must be injective. But why is it surjective? In particular, why does the following counterexample not work?

Let $V = \mathbb{R}$ and $W = \mathbb{W}^2$. The function $(v_1) \times (w_1, w_2) \mapsto v_1 w_1$ is a nondegenerate pairing, but the vector spaces $V$ and $W^*$ have different dimension. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right: according to this asymmetric definition, there is no reason for the map to be surjective. The standard definition for a non-degenerate pairing asks for *both* the left and the right radical to vanish. This appears to have been fixed in my version of the book:

---

[image]

---

Note that according to this standard definition, your pairing is degenerate because $\langle a, (0,b)\rangle = 0$ for all $a$ even though $(0,b) \neq 0$.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear. Thank you!

Comment: what is that version of the book?

Comment: @eraldcoil [This](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/0387906134).